# Error publish in Win2003 Server MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, server

I'm trying to publish my application in a Win 2003 server with IIS6.

And I'm debugging on the other PC and it works ok with Win 2007 Professional and IIS7.

This project uses .NET 4.0 and ASP.NET MVC 4.

If in my PC try to open:

```
http://localhost/Chat/home/index
http://localhost/Chat
```

It works ok.

But on the server, if I type this

```
http://localhost/Chat
```

I have a list of all folders in my project

If I navigate to

```
http://localhost/Chat/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

I get this error:

> Server Error in '/Chat' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for...

If only try with

```
http://localhost/Chat/Home/Index
```

I get this other error:

> The page cannot be found
>
> The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

This is my default `RouteConfig`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
}
```

And I have this code in controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Need I put some library or reference in my project or server?

I have others projects in ASP.NET MVC which work ok and I don't see the difference.

In my `ChatProject -> Configurations -> Web` I set Start Action -> current page and also try with specific page with `home/index` but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at this MVC on IIS 6 walkthrough from Phil Haack? http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/  to verify the various setup needs?

Comment: And is the folder in IIS configured as an application?

Comment: In IIS6 Inside web sites I create a Virtual Directory inside "Default Web Site", but the strange is I have other application in the same way with MVC and its works ok, and the app pools are two differents but with the same configurations.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2003/ Windows Server 2003 extended support ended on July 14, 2015. Not that that means it won't work, but maybe you should consider upgrading the server OS.

Comment: Yes CoderDennis, but this server is from a client and I need put my project in it. I need to know what I need configure to solve this problem. Thanks